# PHP PDO Conversion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am in the process of incorporating PDO into my code but I am finding it hard to accomplish the same tasks that I was comfortable doing before. I feel that I might be missing something. Can someone please provide some guidance on the following code?

First, I have the following function that I converted to use PDO:

```
public function fetchBgnew($whr, $limit){

            $db = Core::getInstance();              
            $res = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT p.id,p.bg,p.bg_desc,p.bg_id,p.user_id, p.pl_id,p.domainurl,p.type,p.price FROM ".USERS_BG." as p left join ".USERS." as u on p.user_id=u.id WHERE u.status !=0 and :whr :limit");
            $res->execute(array(':whr'=>$whr,':limit'=>$limit));                
            $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $cnt = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT p.id FROM ".USERS_BG." as p left join ".USERS." as u on p.user_id=u.id WHERE u.status !=0 and :whr");
            $cnt->execute(array(':whr'=>$whr));             
            $cnt->rowCount();


            return $result = array("data"=>$res, "count"=>$cnt);
        }
```

Second, I want to call the function, but the previous code I was using before took an entire string statement like so:

```
  $bgdataarr = $bgObj->fetchBgnew(" p.pl_id IN (".@implode(',',$barr).") and p.status =1 order by p.id desc", " LIMIT $limit_start,$page_records");
```

I have been working with PDO for about 3 days and I am under the impression that you can't pass a string statement to be prepared or at least I don't know how.

1.What is the proper way to convert the function call secondly stated?

2.Is it possible to convert the function to be able to pass any argument I want to it like before?

Comment: PDO quotes the parameters in prepared statements. Your `:whr` will be treated as a string, and when you look at the query you'd get - it would be `SELECT ..... WHERE u.status !=0 and 'whr content here' 'limit content here'` which gives you invalid SQL syntax. You cannot "safely" pass the column names **and** values and expect that PDO will magically convert it to proper SQL. PDO only quotes values of the columns, not the column names and values at the same time.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to pass column names AND values dynamically, you have to dynamically create the prepared statement by looping trough the array of columns:values and creating a PDO parameter for each column found in the array.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly. You can only pass one value at a time? So, then there really isn't any point on coding functions because every function that I have would take different arguments?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you can't take an array that contains column:value pairs and pass it along as PDOStatement parameter.

What you would have to do is create the entire statement dynamically.

Assuming you have the following array:

```
$whr = array('username' => '12345', 'password' => 'lorem ipsum');
```

And you have your statement which looks like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE :whr");
```

Binding the array to the parameter would produce an invalid SQL (assuming you imploded the array so its result is a string).

What you have to do is create the entire statement dynamically.

```
$query[] = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE";

foreach($whr as $column => $value)
{
    $query[] = "$column = :$column";
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare(implode(' AND ', $query));

// Naturally, you'll have to bind parameters somehow as well
foreach($whr as $column => $value)
{
    $stmt->bindValue($column, $value);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: That is a lot of work. It seems easier to just call it statically.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you consider "statically" to be in this context. Also, the code remains the same size regardless of your array length, so all you need to do is basically use the example provided here.

Comment: The code wouldn't be reusable has every function takes different arguments. It is easier to just write it directly. For instance, your code does not allow for every possible situation nor do I think that can be accomplished.

Comment: The point of the example I posted was so you can see how you can pass an arbitrary amount of parameters to a PDOStatement. The way you build  your statements is up to you, however you cannot pass 1 parameter to PDOStatement and replace it with part of the query. It's not how it works. I don't know the situation of your functions or how they look like, but it might be true that it's easier to write all the queries manually rather than build them this way.